# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'" after installing in Visual Studio Code conda environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, anaconda, anaconda3

I'm seeking to use tensorflow with conda in a anaconda3 python notebook within VSCode.
In the anaconda terminal, on a Windows 10 machine, I used the following commands:

```
conda create --name deeplearning
activate deeplearning
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
conda install -c anaconda jupyter
conda install -c anaconda pandas
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
```

I checked the Anaconda navigator to make sure that all of the files were installed.

I then went to visual studio code, hit `Ctrl - Shift - p` and selected `Python: Select Interpreter` and hit `Python 3.7.16 ('deeplearning') ~\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\python.exe`. `deeplearning` was shown to be active.

While `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` worked fine, commands such as `import tensorflow as tf` resulted in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Same thing happened with `import tensorflow_datasets as tfds`.

I've tried restarting the computer, as well as deleting and remaking the environment. Nothing is working.

How do I get my environment to work properly in VSCode, allowing me to use tensorflow?

Comment: Have you confirmed whether `tensorflow` is installed correctly? Is it showing when you run `conda list` command?

Comment: Yup - `tensorflow` and all the other related packages are there. They're also visible in the Anaconda navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate ways of selecting Interpreters.

If you are using python scripts that is .py files then your way would work.
If you are using a Python Notebook, then you need to select the kernel as shown in the image below.

[Select Kernel on VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFb0x.png)

[Select Python Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5Mbd.png)

[Select your kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRkzM.png)

That should set your notebook to your environment you created in anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

From your error page it is clear that you should be using Jupyter, which is different from `.py` scripts. You can click on the kernel version displayed in the top right corner of the jupyter interface to select `Python 3.7.16 ('deeplearning')` , which is the setting made for jupyter.

[image]

`Python: Select Interpreter` values are specific to the settings for ***.py*** script files.